# Order of makefile targets using %

Tags: makefile

Just out of curiosity, what is the order of executing targets in a makefile with

```
${OBJ_DIR}/%.o: ${SRC_DIR}/%.cpp
```

I noticed it is *not* lexicographic (like `ls -l`).
Is it just random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are built in the order in which make walks the prerequisite graph.

In the simple case where you don't have parallel jobs (no `-j` option), then if you have a target like:

```
prog: foo.o bar.o. baz.o
```

make will first try to build `foo.o`, then `bar.o`, then `baz.o`, then finally `prog`.

If you do enable parallel jobs, then make will still try to *start* builds in the same order but because some builds finish faster than others, you may get different targets building at the same time.

Comment: I was actually asking about `foo.o: foo.c` and `bar.o: bar.c` and `baz.o:baz.c` all originating from `%.o:%.c` ... what is the order to process the targets?

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding pattern rules.  A pattern rule is a template that make can use if it is asked to build a target and there's no explicit rule to do it.  A pattern rule is _not_ an instruction to make that it should go out and find all the possible files that might match those targets, and build them all.  In other words, if you have a makefile with nothing but a pattern in it and you type `make` nothing will happen.  So, as I said in my answer, the order is the one in which make decides to build those targets.

Comment: OK, so you're saying that these `*.o` targets came from some earlier target `prog.exe: foo.o bar.o baz.o` (they did!) and the **order of precedence was determined there**. So I guess my question becomes: why are `$(addprefix ${OBJ_DIR}/,$(notdir $(SRC_FILES:.cpp=.o)))` ordered NOT lexicographically?

Comment: GNU make functions do not change order of their parameters. The order would be the same as `$(SRC_FILES)`, neither `$(patsubst)` nor `$(notdir)` nor `$(addprefix)` changes the order. If you want the result to be sorted, explicitly call `$(sort)` function (which also removes duplicates btw).

Comment: Why would they be ordered lexicographically?  The results of text transformation like `add_prefix`/`notdir` on a variable like `SRC_FILES` will be ordered the same way as the files in `SRC_FILES`.  Whatever order the sources appeared in that variable, is the order in which they object files will be built.

Comment: Now perhaps you will come back with finally the information we needed answer the question originally :), and say that `SRC_FILES` is constructed from using `$(wildcard *.cpp)` or similar... so your real question is, why doesn't `wildcard` return the results in order?  That depends actually on which version of GNU make you have, but some older versions did not guarantee any order: they basically are returned in the order in which they are stored in the directory.  You can use `sort`, as above, if you care.  Newer versions of GNU make (4.3) do sort the output of `wildcard` by default.

Comment: Yes! so the order originates in `$(wildcard  ${SRC_DIR}/*.cpp)`, and my make version is `GNU Make 4.1`. Everything fits! Thanks!